# Possible Stuckness: Google Cloud PubSub to Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a Dataflow streaming job that writes PubSub messages to a file that gets stored in Cloud Storage in 3-minute windows. After a few hours I notice on the "Data Freshness by stages" graph it displays "Possible Stuckness" and "Possible slowness".

I have checked the logs and the info logs displays the follow: "Setting socket default timeout to 60 seconds."; "socket default timeout is 60.0 seconds."; "Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token."; "Refreshing due to a 401 (attempt 1/2)". That last log kept repeating every few minutes for four hours before the job displayed that there was possible slowness/stuckness.

I am not entirely sure what is happening here. Are these logs related to why the job slowed down and got stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "potential stuckness" and "potential slowness" are basically the same thing, they are documented [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/execution-details#stage_progress_for_streaming_jobs).

The logs might be red herrings.

You can view all available logs following [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/logging#navigating_to) by their categories: job-message, worker, worker-startup and etc. Try

- identify if there is any worker logs to determine whether workers are successfully started with dependencies installed;
- search "Operation ongoing" to see whether any work item is taking too much time;
- search if there is any error in workers that is blocking the streaming job from making progress.

Comment: I think I have managed to narrow it down to the part where it assigns a key to the windowed element.  It assigns a random number between 0 and the number of files you want to output. I'm using one of the existing templates for my job and I am trying to understand why that mapping could be slowing down the job at certain times.

Comment: Based on your description, the number sounds like the shard number assigned to each element for writing. You may increase the shardNum in your Cloud Storage write transform. So your final files should look like this xxxxx-{shard_number}-of-{shard_count}.{file_suffix}. If this I/O is the bottleneck of your pipeline, increasing the shard number could help.